How can I get flet to open photos on iOS instead of files?
I am trying to build a Python mobile app using Flet, and one of the things that I need it to do is accept a photo or video from the user. using the flet documentation, I tried the following piece of code:
ft.ElevatedButton("Choose files...",
    on_click=lambda _: file_picker.pick_files(allow_multiple=True))

which on iOS opens the file selector. This is what this piece of code is supposed to do. My question, however, was if there was a way to open the iOS photo selector instead.
I have tried multiple things to accomplish this. One option I considered was using an already written Flutter widget in Flet to accomplish this, but my lack of experience in both flutter and dart has made this process very difficult.
I was wondering if anyone had found an easier way to access the iOS photo selector instead of the files.
